# Any way of filtering questions by user rep? If not, why not?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

The site has so many poor questions on front page that it's becoming tiresome. Is there a way to filter the question only from users above a certain amount of rep? (say 1500.)

I'm not asking to stop new users from asking questions, but to have, sometimes, the possibility to isolate the interesting content from the "noise".
As it stands, I'm spending more time requesting to close questions than answering or reading nice posts and therefore I'm coming less an less to this site.

On the technical side, it could be a tag that's only available to some users or a multi-criteria filter.

If it doesn't exist, do you think it would a nice feature or not?

Comment: Yes, just search user [Yoichi Oishi](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi)

Comment: Oh, I know. I was being sassy because the only high rep person posting good _questions_ with any frequency is Yoichi. And that's all he does (mostly). Lots and lots of great questions. You can sort users by rep, but there doesn't seem a way to do that by # of questions too. Wait, isn't there a database query one can make....?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to create a data.SE query to get this for you:

> [Questions by users with high rep](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/616934/)

I arbitrarily chose the most recent 20, and rep >= 20,000.

Comment: Please anyone if you can figure out how to do links directly to the question please tell.

Comment: BINGO!!! http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/617028/questions-by-users-with-rep1000  even simpler than I thought. A query that gives the unanswered-still open-less than one year old-and-from user-with-more-than-a-1000-rep-points including hyperlink to afforementioned question. Thanks for your help. If you want you can use the link to edit your answer and I'll accept it .

Comment: ugh...     "Posts.Id as [Post Link]" not "Posts.Id as [Posts Link]".

Comment: @P.O. You don't need to construct the ugly URL string, just use 'Posts.Id as [Post Link]'

Comment: @P.O. Fixed link.